# Can't upgrade the project to CakePHP-2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade, cakephp-2.0

The project was developed with CakePHP-1.3

Now I'm trying to upgrade to CakePHP-2.0

I have renamed all controllers and mode with the CakePHP-2.0 conventions.

Now if I reloads the page I got error like this:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property PostsController::$Auth has no effect [APP/Controller/PostsController.php, line 11]
```

The code:

PostsController:

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions =
        array('index','view','archive','listarchive','viewfromcategory','tags','aboutme','contact','polls');
```

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Acl', 'Session', 'Auth','RequestHandler');
    //var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Js','Session','Cache');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Js','Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        //Configure AuthComponent           
        $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';

        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display');

        //$this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index');
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Cake 2.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html):

> AuthComponent
>
> The AuthComponent was entirely re-factored for 2.0, this was done to
>   help reduce developer confusion and frustration. In addition,
>   AuthComponent was made more flexible and extensible. You can find out
>   more in the [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) guide.

You are getting that error because of the changes to the cakephp core, so you should adjust your code according to the new guides.

I have encountered the same issue when modifying the data array inside the controller:

```
$this->data['foo'] = 'bar';
```

and had to switch this to use the new CakeRequest object:

```
$this->request->data['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix warning you can try follow:

In your "PostsController" replace:

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions =
    array('index','view','archive','listarchive','viewfromcategory','tags','aboutme','contact','polls');
```

By

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('index','view','archive','listarchive','viewfromcategory','tags','aboutme','contact','polls'));
```